# Как сделать закругление углов и прозрачность?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как сделать закругление углов и прозрачность?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прозрачность:

```
$('.className').css('opacity', '0.5');
```

Закругление углов для разных браузеров, местами древних) на CSS :

```
behavior: url(/border-radius.htc);
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
```

[border-radius.htc](http://narod.ru/disk/18791273001/border-radius.htc.html) для эксплорера.

P.S. наиболее кросс-браузерные решения - картинки (закругленные края), но поверьте они того не стоят :) CSS-стилей вполне достаточно

Answer (score 3):

Зачем так сильно с доп. библиотеками жизнь усложнять?! А не хватит

```
$.('.class_name').css('opacity', '0.5');
```

или

```
$.('.class_name').css('border-radius', '5');
```

???

Comment: Поддерживаю, обычного css вполне достаточно, нет смысла навешивать кучу всяких библиотек :)

Answer (score 2):

Надо подобрать соответствующий плагин. Например, для закругления углов - [jQuery Corner](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/). Тогда закругление блока #box выглядит делается так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#box").corner();
});
```

А для добавления прозрачности, непрозрачности - [jQuery Transify](http://jorenrapini.com/blog/css/transify-a-jquery-plugin-to-easily-apply-transparency-opacity-to-an-elements-background). Тогда добавление прозрачности к блоку #box делается так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#box').transify();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделать стиль не стилем?

Флэш, Java, PHP+GD. Попиксельная отрисовка с JS))

Comment: мсье знает толк в извращениях